# Android handle activity before create and finish that

Tags: android

I'm trying to my application to handle activity if `getExtras'a` opend activity is null then finish activity and dont run, for example by this code I can `putExtra` to activity:

```
lv_categories.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent i = new Intent(G.context, ActivityOnlineCategoryContent.class);
        i.putExtra("id", categoryLists.get(position).getId());
        G.currentActivity.startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

now I want to check this Extra in `ActivityOnlineCategoryContent` activity, if bundle is null then finish and dont run

```
@Override
protected void onResum() {
    super.onResume();

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = 0;
    if (extras != null) {
        id = extras.getInt("id");
    } else {
        UC.toast(UC.getString(R.string.unable_resolve_data));
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

**PROBLEM:**

finish ‍‍`ActivityOnlineCategoryContent` activity if bundle is null, that means is: problem is activity dont destroy and finish if `extras` is null

Comment: What do you want exactly

Comment: what problem getting with current code

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK finish ‍‍`ActivityOnlineCategoryContent` activity if bundle is null

Comment: Write down the snippet inside onCreate() too

Answer (score 0):

You need to check only for your values.
like (Try this)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    /* Bundle.getInt Returns the value associated with the given key, or 0 if no mapping of the desired type exists for the given key.*/
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int id = 0;
    if (extras != null && extras.getInt("id") != 0) {
        id = extras.getInt("id");
    } else {
        UC.toast(UC.getString(R.string.unable_resolve_data));
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is activity dont destroy and finish if `extras` is null

Comment: It will be finish as per your code, might be your extras not null, debug step by step and observer the  value of extras.